# Python reading in file and creating new lines

Tags: python, string, special-characters

I currently have a file that is comma separated and everything is on a single line. I would like to read it in through python and create a new line where it see's a comma. I am going to perform some operations on each line, then I would like to export each line to a file. I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `split` string method.

```
'a,b,c,b'.split(',') -> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b']
```

So you can use it to process and write into file

```
for row in data.split(','):
    file.write(row + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split all the lines into a list

```
with open("infile") as f:
    lines = f.read().split(",")
    with open("outfile.txt", "w") as f1:
        for line in lines:
            f1.write(line+"\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

sample `file`:

```
this,is a,comma,separated,line
```

sample code:

```
with open('file', 'r') as f:
    f = f.read().strip('\n').split(',') # strip will get rid of \n at end of the line

with open('outfile', 'w') as o:
    for line in f:
        # do something with the line here
        o.write(line + '\n')
```

sample `outfile`:

```
this
is a  
comma
separated
line
```